# Is Law SE a good place to get feedback on briefs before they are submitted?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have prepared an initial brief and I would like to get some ideas on how to make it better. I feel that my attorney has lost me my case and am not sure who else to get legal help from on a pro-bono basis.

Assuming that I can share my brief on here and strip any personally-identifying information, could I paste it into the body of the question, or put it as a file that can be downloaded?

Comment: Have you filed yet or are you still within the deadline? what type of case are you litigating? what type of brief did you prepare (that is, for motion in trial court, brief on appeal, or other)? I'm aware this question was posted a month and a half ago, but I saw your post just yesterday.

Comment: I'm filing a civil action based on the last comment on the first answer of this question. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/27424/are-there-any-social-security-loopholes-i-can-use-to-justify-my-inability-to-pay
However, I am concerned that new evidence will not be admissible based on this recent finding, and my attorney failed to maintain active communication after telling him about this new finding.
I have a few weeks left to file the case. I was not able to get my LegalShield provider firm to find any attorneys under the B5 contract, so they closed my file and referred me to the bar.

Answer (score 5):

Alas, we have a policy against giving legal advice on the site. Litigated matters in which one questions the sufficiency of counsel would seem to fall into this category.

However, if you can extract specific questions about the law, I'm sure people would be happy to take a look.

Answer (score 4):

**No:** Law.SE is not a discussion site.  Questions should be scoped to a single topic, and questions whose answers would be primarily opinion-based are "[off-topic](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)."

Answer (score 2):

Although I myself did and recommend litigation *in pro per*, another problem I see with your idea is that fully reviewing users' briefs would be very time-consuming and therefore unrealistic.

Moreover, this would require at least some acquaintance with his/her case. Without enough context or acquaintance, even contributors' well-intended efforts might turn out to be ineffective or inaccurate.

Part of the steep learning curve a *pro se* litigant needs to undergo consists of reading judicial opinions and --where available-- briefs from other cases. That is a more realistic approach for learning how to draft one's own briefs and advance his legal arguments.